# What does "entertain in their service" imply?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in a chapter in my history book which was:

> A century ago the British arrived in Hindostan and gradually entertained troops in their service and became masters of every state. [Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lehs302.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiJ5q-skoniAhVJWH0KHQU0DrEQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1x1elGROXAK658lMUoDDMD)

Now, I'm unable to figure out what "entertained in service" imply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange use of the word "entertain".

The Cambridge dictionary [has this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/entertain):

> **entertain** verb (INVITE) ​ [ I or T ]
>
> to invite someone to your home
>   and give food and drink to them:
>
> *We entertain a lot of people, mainly
>   business associates of my wife's.*
>
> *Now that I live on my own, I don't
>   entertain much.*

The Oxford dictionary [provides the following](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/entertain) in the “fine print”:

> Origin Late Middle English: from French entretenir, based on Latin
>   **inter ‘among’ + tenere ‘to hold’.** The word originally meant ‘maintain,
>   continue’, later ‘maintain in a certain condition, treat in a certain
>   way’, also ‘show hospitality’ (late 15th century).

In your example, the meaning of the word "entertain" is probably a very archaic usage: a direct reference to the origin of the word: “to hold” + “among”.

Using this definition, the following sentence:

> A century ago the British arrived in Hindostan and gradually entertained troops in their service and became masters of every state

Would mean:

> A century ago the British arrived in [the subcontinent] and gradually **brought troops into it** and **controlled all of its regions.**

This is very unusual writing — I assume your example is British and from the early twentieth century, or earlier. American English would never use the word “entertain” this way.

Comment: The cited text isn't *actually* "British". See [this **1943** link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22arrived+in+Hindostan+and+gradually+entertained+troops%22&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdw4GpxYniAhUESxUIHWDNCDgQpwUIIg&biw=1422&bih=739&dpr=1.2), which cites the source as "contemporary" (i.e.- from around **1857**, a date referenced in the linked "footnote"). And that more extended context includes reference to ***the British***, which strongly implies it was written by an ***Indian*** (an early example of "Indian English"?).